# Optimizing a Nested Loop Algorithm for Maximum Efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, nested-loops

I'm working on a project that involves processing a large dataset with nested loops, and I'm struggling to optimize my code for maximum efficiency. Here's my current approach, which I know is not efficient:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        for k in range(L):
            # Perform some computations
```

In this code, N, M, and L are the sizes of the loops, and within the innermost loop, I'm performing some computations that take a significant amount of time.

I've tried various techniques like memoization and parallelization, but I'm still not achieving the performance I need. Are there any advanced optimization strategies or libraries that I can use to speed up this nested loop processing significantly? I'm open to suggestions in Python or any other language that can provide a substantial performance boost.

Comment: You'll have to show the 'some computation' inside ...

Comment: What are the constraints, what are your current results and what is the actual problem. Looping like this is O(n^3) and in many cases the approach is the issue, not the implementation.

Comment: All you've shown is that you have a three-deep loop nest.  How could anyone possibly suggest improvements with no more information than that?  You need to show the computation being performed inside the loop for any meaningful suggestions to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using multiprocessing in linux system

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool, Array, Manager
import numpy as np
N = 20
M = 20
L = 20
ret = Array('f', N*M*L)
def calcul(i, j, k, num,):
    global ret
    ret._obj[num] = i+j+k
    kk = 0

def main():
    p = Pool(2)
    num = 0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            for k in range(L):
                # Perform some computations
                # calcul(i, j, k, num)
                p.apply_async(calcul, args=(i, j, k, num,))
                # p.apply(calcul, args=(i, j, k, num,))
                num += 1
    p.close()
    p.join()
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
    kk = []
    for i in range(N*M*L):
        kk.append(ret._obj[i])
    k = 0
```

in win10, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Performance optimisation is a complicated field and typically requires making use of all available information about the specific problem. Your 'Perform Some Computations' comment doesn't provide any details at all. However, I'll try to give some general pointers.

Your main options are as follows.

1. Algorithmic improvements.
2. Efficient code optimisations.
3. Using a fast compiled language (e.g. c, c++).
4. Using a fast compiled language with SIMD.
5. Using a fast compiled language with multithreading.
6. Using a fast compiled language with multithreading and SIMD.
7. Using GPGPU or other accelerators.

Sometimes, there are opportunities for performance gains by using a different algorithm. It is often the case that faster algorithms are more complicated to code, so more work to write test and maintain than simple algorithms, so their benefit needs to considered against their costs. Also, a common mistake people often make is to assume that algorithms with faster asymptotic complexity are 'faster' but they may not always be.

Code optimisations typically means using more variables to avoid repeating computations.

Sometimes, just switching from a 'slow' language like python (though it has many fast library functions) to a language that can be compiled with performance optimisations can give massive performance improvements. Billions of arithmetic operations per second are possible on modern CPUs on a single thread.

If the algorithm can be parallelised, then the following can also be considered. Tasks that are memory, IO, or network bound may not benefit much from parallelisation.

Further speed-up can sometimes be made by using your CPUs vector instructions. Sometimes compilers can figure out how to make use of these themselves if the program is compiled with those instructions enabled. These builds can be quite brittle though, and a small change, or even a re-compilation with another compiler might lose that optimisation. Programs can be manually vectorised using intrinsics but such code is no longer portable across different CPU architectures. One may have to write a slower portable version as well. These SIMD instructions are great for optimising code that has a short runtime, of the order of <1m machine cycles or so (~100 us). Other ways of parallelising code like GPGPU and multithreading come with overheads that make them unsuitable for such instances. SIMD instructions are generally quite primitive, so there may not be much opportunity for gains if you require complicated maths functions like trig functions and logs etc. Tens of billions of arithmetic operations per second are possible on modern CPUs with SIMD vector instructions on a single thread.

Multithreading makes use of more of the CPUs cores to execute code in parallel. Not all tasks can be parallelised, but when they can, provided the work to be done takes significantly more time than the cost of starting the threads, then performance can often be improved by a factor of the order of the number of CPU cores available. Multi threaded programs however, can be significantly more difficult to write, test and maintain than their single threaded equivalents though there are tools like OpenMP that can make it much easier. Sometimes when the main part of an algorithm can not be parallelised, it can still be broken up into a few threads to make the overall runtime not much longer than that of the most time consuming dependency chain. For example, one thread can be loading a new batch of data for the main algorithm to process while another thread is processing the previous batch.

To squeeze the absolute maximum computational performance from a modern CPU, you may be able write your program using both multithreading and SIMD. Tens of billions of arithmetic operations per second are possible on modern CPUs per thread.

As fast as modern CPUs are at running parallelisable code, modern GPUs are much faster. In 2023, a high end GPU can execute tens of trillions of arithmetic operations per second. There is a significant overhead though, passing data and commands between the host CPU and the GPU. It makes the most sense to use GPGPU (General Purpose GPU (Graphics Processing Unit)) computing for tasks with runtimes over 1ms. That can still mean billions of operations. There's also a runtime compilation which might take a second or so at program startup. CUDA has become the dominant API for this purpose followed by OpenCL, Vulkan Kompute and a few other less well known options. GPU architectures vary significantly across vendors and models and choosing a good architecture for the required task can make a big difference to the performance achieved. The performance of modern GPUs in memory bandwidth, integer, fp16, or fp64 can vary in unexpected ways across models so attention should be paid to particular architectures' capabilities.

Comment: There are more options if you have a cluster, but I didn't cover those.